# Flash builder, embed json compile error

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash-builder, embed

I am using flash builder 4.7.
I tried to embed a json file while I got an error says:"../strings.json is of an unknown file 
 type which can't be embedded".

Here is my code.
[Embed(source="../media/data/strings.json"), mimeType="application/octet-stream"]
public static const JsonData:Class;

I have no idea how to fix it.

I am using AIR SDK 3.4

I want to use embedded method since it's always annoying to access local resource (the global flash setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the syntax you posted for embedding json file is incorrect.
Please make it correct, it should be like

[Embed(source="a.json", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public var jsonData:Class;

Then you can access json data like this:-

var str:String = new String(new jsonData());
var obj:Object = JSON.parse(str);

Please make sure your a.json file must have a valid json data.